# Mixed ASP.NET Site Forms Authentication Redirecting to the wrong place

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, forms-authentication

In my web config

```
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow roles="Employee" />
</authorization>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Then when I go to the page

```
    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Location: /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Tue, 23 Oct 2012 22:34:55 GMT
    Content-Length: 145

    <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
    <h2>Object moved to <a href="/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f">here</a>.</h2>
    </body></html>
```

Why does LogOn not give me that but rather Login?

IIS 7.5

Site is

- Classic Asp
- ASP.Net

using the forms auth "hack" from

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/04/tip-trick-integrating-asp-net-security-with-classic-asp-and-non-asp-net-urls.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this key to your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Account/LogOn" />
</appSettings>
```

Evidently there can be some redirection going on within the DLL's to a different "loginUrl", especially if the WebMatrix dll's are in the path.